I am not able to create my first react app. Can anyone help me?
PS C:\Users\rkmgr\OneDrive\Desktop\react course> npx create-react-app my-app
npm error code ENOENT
npm error syscall lstat
npm error path C:\Users\rkmgr\OneDrive\Desktop\react course\%APPDATA%\npm
npm error errno -4058
npm error enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat 'C:\Users\rkmgr\OneDrive\Desktop\react course\%APPDATA%\npm'
npm error enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm error enoent
npm error A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\rkmgr\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2024-07-18T18_12_42_044Z-debug-0.log

I'm typing this (npx create-react-app my-app) and then the error is occuring.

create-react-app (CRA) is kind of dead. You should spend time on something else. Google for alternatives. BR

create-react-app (CRA) is deprecated. Use Vite to setup your project. Been using it for years, fast and comes with a cool set of tools

Expanding on what was said by @RoarS. CRA is no longer recommended by the React team. See https://react.dev/learn/start-a-new-react-project#can-i-use-react-without-a-framework for helping choosing. However, if you just want to learn react use Vite. If you are building a full stack app go with Next or Remix. If you are building a content heavy site use Astro.

This is something with NPM not being installed correctly, or your path.
Try checking your npm version or reinstall it
Make sure it is added to your PATH
Try running npm cache clean --force
Try renaming the folder to something with no spaces/dashes or special chars.
Hope any of that solves the problem
